# Disable SSL for one page

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, drupal

I have a Drupal site that is using SSL for every page. I have the htaccess file configured to force SSL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.org/$1 [R,L]
```

I now want to disable SSL for just one page. The blog rss feed, because feedburner will not parse https pages. The link is http://domain.org/blog/rss.xml. I have tried multiple things and the only one that even sort of works is below. However it just creates a redirect loop.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/rss.xml(.*)$ http://domain.org/blog/rss.xml [R,L]
```

Here is an update of what I tried based on previous answers. It still does not work. Everything seems normal except when I try to go to the blog/rss.xml address (either https or http) it just redirects to the https version of the homepage.

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
  RewriteRule !^blog/rss\.xml https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC,NE,L]

  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(blog/rss.xml)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Feedburner still exists?!

Comment: Yup! Client wants to track RSS feed activity or subscribers, etc. Even though I told them there is no accurate way to track it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule !^blog/rss\.xml https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blog/rss.xml)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried your suggestion and when I navigate to domain.org/blog/rss.xml it redirects me to the homepage instead instead.

Comment: Did you try: `http://domain.org/blog/rss.xml` OR `https://domain.org/blog/rss.xml` ? Make sure these are rules are first rules before any other rule and you test in a new browser.

Comment: Either of those I try just sends me to the homepage. I understand that you said those rules should be first but that didn't seem to work either. I included what I tried in the original questions.

Comment: You still didn't answer a simple question. What is **exact URL** you enter in your browser?

Comment: http://domain.org/blog/rss.xml redirects to the homepage. https://domain.org/blog/rss.xml redirects to the home page. Domain is obviously not the EXACT url but I cannot give out the EXACT URL here in this forum.

Comment: No I don't want to know your real domain jus the remaining URL is good enough. Open Firebug and then enter `http://domain.org/blog/rss.xml` in browser and check under Net tab what redirects you get.